# npm install -g <package> fails with E401

Tags: vue.js, npm

This just started this morning, but in trying to do `npm update -g @vue/cli` or (after removing the old version) `npm i -g @vue/cli` I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @vue/cli@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-11-28T13_22_01_121Z-debug.log
```

The log file gives no further information other than showing a couple stack traces around the 401 error (which just indicate that fetching the repo was unauthorized, etc).

I am on node 11.3.0 and npm 6.4.1.  Looks like a new version of @vue/cli was published yesterday, so is it possible that's the issue?  Other packages seem to be installing fine for me.

Comment: Go to into the app project folder and try to delete the .npmrc hidden file.

Comment: @javimovi change that to the global .npmrc and make it an answer.  That's correct.  In my case the global .npmrc is located in my user home directory.